# Spectrum Same External Table Shows in Multiple Schemas (svv_external_tables)

Tags: external-tables, amazon-redshift-spectrum

It's a really simple test actually. I create a couple external schemas and create an external table in one of the schemas and then querying svv_external_tables shows the table exists in ALL schemas!! What am I missing?

```
create external schema mytestschema from data catalog 
database 'mytestdb' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/spectrumrole'
;

create external table mytestdb.mytestschema.newtable (
col1 varchar(200),
col2 varchar(200),
col3 varchar(200)
)
partitioned by (cycle_date varchar(20) )
stored as parquet
location 's3://s3loc';

select * from svv_external_tables;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External schema doesn't hold the table descriptions, it just hold the connection parameters to a database in data catalog. Or put the other way - whatever is in the data catalog database is shown in every external schema that points to it.